# C# Conversion of lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

What is the way to convert the following into lambda expression?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Current Thread Id is {0}:",
         Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("I will be used as Callback");
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could definitely write this as a lambda expression:

```
// The underscore is simply a placeholder for the "state"
// parameter that the WaitCallback delegate expects - you could
// use any character but you must specify one as lamba expressions cannot
// omit parameters like anonymous functions can.
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current Thread Id is {0}:",
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("I will be used as Callback");
    });
```

But remember that a lambda expression has no meaning outside of your source code. The C# compiler will convert your lambda expression right back to the code you have now.

A lambda expression is simply syntactic sugar that you can use to express an anonymous function - the compiler will convert this to either an anonymous function or an expression tree.

Comment: Andrew ,what is the use of "_" (underscore) ?

Comment: Sorry, yes it's in the comment.  Basically you need to throw *something* in there to be a placeholder.

Comment: The `(_) => ...` parameter would be more self-explanatory as `state => ...`.

Comment: FYI, you don't need those parentheses around the underscore. You can just do: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( _ => { /* block omitted */ });